# Is border-style mandatory or optional? Discrepant behaviour seen

Tags: css

In CSS I have found that omitting border-style did not matter when coding as:

```
input{
/*here border style is not mentioned*/
border-width:  3px;
border-color: red;

}
```

The border was still appearing in this case. However border would not appear if coded as below:

```
input{
border: 3px red; /*here border style is not mentioned*/

}
```

I also tested on w3school editors please see the screen shots with border style removed. Why is border appearing in the 3rd screenshot?
What am I missing?

```
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-color1
https://imgur.com/xgTVpmN

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border
https://imgur.com/b7blLMH

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_form_focus2
https://imgur.com/1wxD5OG
```

Comment: Default `border-style` is `none`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: The <input> element has a border by default (in the user agent stylesheet) so that's where the border style comes from. Most elements don't have one by default, so you'll have to put one in explicitly.

Comment: Thanks but what is the difference between 
input{
border-width:  3px;
border-color: red;
}
and
input{
border: 3px red; 
}
Both mention same attributes but why is border appearing only for the first one? Can you please check the w3schoolslinks I have mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Meenohara See DaniP's answer. The `border` shorthand resets all individual styles that aren't mentioned to their initial values. I.E. `border:3px red` is exactly the same as `border:3px none red`.

Comment: @Mr Lister. I aoplogise for asking too much. Can you please check the links and screenshots mentioned? I am seeing un-uniform behaviour

Comment: @Meenohara I'm not sure which of the examples you have problems with. The seeming inconsistencies come from changing the styles, but not the text. For instance, the first p still says "A solid red border" even though it no longer has a solid border style...

Comment: I have problems with 2 and 3. When you say styles do you mean that in one case it is "p"(link2) and in the ither case it is "input"(link 3)?
In case 2 border cease to appear whil in case 3 border still appears.
Both mention     
border-color:  #ccc;
    border-width: 3px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input` elements have a default `border` definition so when you overwrite each property like in the first example you still see it because you aren't changing the style but with the shorthand you are overwriting the entire default value, and if you don't set any value for style on the shorthand it will take the initial value of the property that in this case is `none`.

> The border CSS property is a shorthand property for setting all individual border property values at once: border-width, border-style, and border-color. As with all shorthand properties, any individual value that is not specified is set to its corresponding initial value.

&

> Note: The default value of border-style is none.

[From MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Comment: The screen shots are not showing here but 
input{
/*here border style is not mentioned*/
border-width:  3px;
border-color: red;
}

is showing different results. Please also check the screenshots and links if you would like to see how the code is giving output

Comment: Not sure how else to explain. Again, an <input> has a border by default, so setting the `border-width` property changes the border width. A <p> does not have a border by default, so setting its `border-width` changes nothing.

Comment: Thank you @Mr Lister I understood now. The difference is about "p" and "input". I hope I have got this right

Comment: @DaniP Thanks could not tag two people. Your answer is quite clear

Comment: @Meenohara np mate hope you have it clear now, p doesn't have any value in border for default.